# Convert Object (Array?) To String

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have acquired some code but the developer in not contactable.
It contains a javascript object (array?) that I am trying to turn its contents into a string.
As I believe it may include some data I need.

The object is called submitDataDisplay.
At the moment its content is ouput to the bottom of the page (I believe oit is this object that contains the data), which I can copy and paste but my aim is to save it to a text file, programmatically.
I might be right off the ball here and this is not possible but I want to give it a shot.

I have tried using JSON.stringify(obj) to see the contents, but this does not work as it does not get all the values as I am unable to add the relevant row items into the command during the loop.

This is from the html file:

```
updateRemark(sheet);

$("#J_timingSubmit").click(function(ev){

    var sheetStates = sheet.getSheetStates();
    var rowsCount = dimensions[0];
    var $submitDataDisplay = $("#J_dataDisplay") ;

    $submitDataDisplay.html("<b>Raw Data Submitted:</b><br/>[<br/>");

    for(var row= 0, rowStates=[]; row<rowsCount; ++row){
        rowStates = sheetStates[row];
        $submitDataDisplay.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;[ '+rowStates+' ]'+(row==rowsCount-1?'':',')+'<br/>');

    }


    $submitDataDisplay.append(']');
```

This is from the js file, which I think is the relevant part:

```
initSheet();
eventBinding();


var publicAPI = {

    /*
     *  
     * @return : [[1,0,0,...,0,1],[1,0,0,...,0,1],...,[1,0,0,...,0,1]]
     * */
    getSheetStates : function(){
        return sheetModel.getSheetStates();
    },

    setRemark : function(row,html){
        if($.trim(html)!==''){
            $(thisSheet.find(".TimeSheet-row")[row]).find(".TimeSheet-remark").prop("title",html).html(html);
        }
    },

    getDefaultRemark : function(){
        return sheetOption.remarks.default;
    },

};

return publicAPI;
```

This is the data that gets posted to the bottom of the web page:

```
Raw Data Submitted:
[
  [ 1,1,0,1,0,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],
  [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ]
]
```

I have added to the last line of code:

```
    $submitDataDisplay.append(']');
    console.log(Object.values($submitDataDisplay));
```

This gives me some good data. It includes an InnerText entry that contains all the data I need.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or show the code where you are facing the problem in?

Comment: That is the code that I think is relevant. I click a button which runs the js function and saves the output to the web page. The code from the js file is the part I believe  is relevant. I don't want to post the whole file as it is 800+ lines. I just need advice is it storing data into an array and what would i use to get the data out? Not after complete code, just after advice if I am on right track with the object i mentioned.

Comment: Post the sample data ,  then I can show you how to format it

Comment: Thanks Daggie I have done so. I have also got the console log working that show *lots* of data but has an InnerText entry that contains the data I need.

Comment: I just need to know how to get that innertext into a variable I can use

Comment: If it helps I do not require any line breaks (carriage returns) or spaces in the resulting variable. The data i need works just as well without them (with it all on one line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$submitDataDislay` is neither an object now an array, it is a DOM node representing an HTML element on your web page, fetched by jQuery.

The code you posted reads data from an array named `sheetStates` to write its content to the DOM node so that it is displayed in the browser.

If you want to store this data in a string instead, you can put it in a string variable, like this:

```
updateRemark(sheet);

$("#J_timingSubmit").click(function(ev){

    var sheetStates = sheet.getSheetStates();
    var rowsCount = dimensions[0];
    var data = "Raw Data Submitted:\n\n[\n";

    for(var row= 0, rowStates=[]; row<rowsCount; ++row){
        rowStates = sheetStates[row];
        data += '  [ '+rowStates+' ]'+(row==rowsCount-1?'':',')+'\n';

    }

    data += ']';

    console.log(data);
}
```

This will print the data to the console.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is brilliant. Works better than I could have hoped. Thanks too for the information on the DOM node subject.  Something else for me to research and try to learn.